# multilevel grep

Tags: regex

I have a series of HTML files that are formatted like this:

```
cinema name
 film 1
  showtime 1
  showtime 2
  ...

 film 2
  showtime 1
  showtime 2
  showtime 3
  ...
```

the name of the cinema is listed only one, at the top; then there is a list of films (any number of films could be here, from 1 to n), and then a list of showtimes (again, it could be 1 or more during the day.

i would like to extract this info using grep and output something like:

```
cinema name - film 1 - showtime 1
cinema name - film 1 - showtime 2
cinema name - film 2 - showtime 1
cineme name - film 2 - showtime 2
cinema name - film 2 - showtime 3
etc.
```

however, i'm not sure whether/how i can accomplish this with grep. is it possible? if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to solve every problem with a single regex. In this case, I would just figure out which sort of line I have by the leading whitespace, remember what the values for the cinema and movie are, then print them all together when I run into a showtime. Although this solution is in Perl, you could do the same thing in any language you choose:

```
#!perl
use v5.10;

my( $cinema, $film );
while( <DATA> ) {
    chomp;
    if( /\A\S/ )            { $cinema = $_ }
    elsif( /\A\s(\S.*)/ )   { $film = $1 }
    elsif( /\A\s\s(\S.*)/ ) { say "$cinema - $film - $1" }
    }   


__END__
Regal 9
 Jaws
  15:00
  19:00
  21:00

 Star Wars
  16:00
  17:00
  18:00

AMC 18
 E.T.
  12:00
  14:00

 Black Sheep
  22:00
  01:00
  03:00
```

Here's an ugly Perl one-liner version of that:

```
perl -lne '(/\A\S/ and $c=$_) || (/\A\s(\S.*)/ and $f=$1) || (/\A\s\s(\S.*)/ and print"$c - $f - $1")' movies.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

A single expression isn't possible, but you can do it in five:

Remove blank lines (simplifies some stuff):
    Find: "\n\n"
    Replace: "\n"

Fill down the films:

(Finds a showtime prefixed by any number of previous showtimes after a film. The film is captured and then added to the beginning of the showtime.)

```
Find: "(?<=\n ([^ \n].+)(\n  .*)*)\n  "
Replace: "\n  $1 - "
```

Fill down the cinema:

(Finds a showtime prefixed by any number of previous showtimes OR films after a cinema. The cinema is captured and then added to the beginning of the showtime.)

```
Find: "(?<=(?:^|\n)([^ \n].+)(\n {1,2}.*)*)\n  "
Replace: "\n  $1 - "
```

Remove non-showtime lines:

```
Find: "(?<=^|\n)(?!  ).*\n"
Replace: ""
```

Trim showtimes:

```
Find: "\n  "
Replace: "\n"
```

All of this is untested and assumes .NET-like regex syntax with `\n` line terminators. Adjust for taste.